# Python: Tkinter OK button callback function

Tags: python, user-interface, callback, tkinter

I'm working on my very first Python GUI and I'm trying to modify this [tkinter example](http://zetcode.com/gui/tkinter/introduction/), but I simply cannot figure out how to write a callback function for the OK button that will pass on the entered value to the main program.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from Tkinter import Tk, BOTH, StringVar, IntVar
from ttk import Frame, Button, Style, Label, Entry

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Get Value")
        self.style = Style()
        self.style.theme_use("default")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        valueLabel = Label(self, text="Value: ")
        valueLabel.place(x=10, y=10)
        value=StringVar(None)
        value.set("this is the default value")
        valueEntry=Entry(self, textvariable=value)
        valueEntry.place(x=70, y=10)

        quitButton = Button(self, text="Quit", command=self.quit)
        quitButton.place(x=10, y=50)

        okButton = Button(self, text="OK", command=self.quit)
        okButton.place(x=120, y=50)

def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("220x100+300+300")
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've read a gazillion of tutorials, but none of them explains this clearly. Theoretically, I should be able to get the selected value with value.get(), but I keep getting error messages no matter where I put it. Also, AFAIK, I should be able to define a default value with value.set(), but this doesn't seem to have an effect, since the text box is empty when I run the program.

1. What is the easiest way to pass on values to the main python program after root.mainloop() terminates? (The actual dialog box contains several entry boxes for entering string and integer values.)

   I.e. I want to be able to use something like:

   ```
   root = Tk()
   root.geometry("220x100+300+300")
   app = Example(root)
   root.mainloop()
   print value
   print value2        
   print value3
   ```
2. How do I define default values for entry boxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change every occurrence of the `value` variable with `self.value`. This should fix it and the default value will be displayed.

**UPDATE**

```
from Tkinter import Tk, BOTH, StringVar, IntVar
from ttk import Frame, Button, Style, Label, Entry

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def showMe(self):
        print(self.value.get())

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Get Value")
        self.style = Style()
        self.style.theme_use("default")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        valueLabel = Label(self, text="Value: ")
        valueLabel.place(x=10, y=10)
        self.value=StringVar(None)
        self.value.set("this is the default value")
        valueEntry=Entry(self, textvariable=self.value)
        valueEntry.place(x=70, y=10)

        quitButton = Button(self, text="Quit", command=self.quit)
        quitButton.place(x=10, y=50)

        okButton = Button(self, text="OK", command=self.showMe)
        okButton.place(x=120, y=50)




def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("220x100+300+300")
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: @NemoXXX, did you change `textvariable=value` to `textvariable=self.value`?

Comment: If I change textvariable=value to textvariable=self.value I get the following error message:
 `valueEntry=Entry(self, self.textvariable=value)
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression`

Comment: @NemoXXX, No, change it to `textvariable=self.value` not `self.textvariable=value`. That's what the error says you did

Comment: That change gives me the following error:
    `valueEntry=Entry(self, textvariable=self.value)
AttributeError: Example instance has no attribute 'value'`

Comment: @NemoXXX,You only changed that one line. You should replace all occurences of `value`. First change `value=StringVar(None)` to `self.value=StringVar(None)`. Second, change `value.set("this is the default value")` to `self.value.set("this is the default value")`. Finally change `valueEntry=Entry(self, textvariable=value)` to `valueEntry=Entry(self, textvariable=self.value)`.

Comment: Thanks for being so patient with me. After applying your changes the text box finally shows the default value, but I still don't know how to access it.  

If I add the following def under initUI(self):

`    def showme():
        print self.value.get()`

and update the OK command as follows:
        
`okButton = Button(self, text="OK", command=self.showme)`        
        
I get the following error message

    `return self.func(*args)
TypeError: showme() takes no arguments (1 given)`

Can you please post an updated version of my script that returns the value?

Answer (score 0):

Both your quitButton and okButton call the self.quit functions. So no mater what value you enter when you press the OK button you are calling the quit function which has its own problems as well outside the scope of your question.
Try to define value as self.value and make the okButton call a function that does: print self.value.get().

Comment: I'm aware of the fact that both buttons are doing exactly the same thing, I merely added the function, because the form won't load otherwise.